# SQL Server : how to get top 5 data from 4 Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need your help on this. Below is my table of data:

[image]

As you can see above picture, (F)Atekizu x4, (B)Dense x3, (B)DIP Stain x2, (F)D-Scratch x2, (F)Other Stain x2 ....

I want to get Top 5 of which most defect have been hit the surface. Below is the example of the output that I need to show:

[image]

Please help. Thank you.

I use below solutions to get the answer as below:

[image]

But can you help to pivot it? I try but the result I got is:

[image]

Below are my syntax to create the pivot:

```
SELECT [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
FROM
(
    SELECT top 5 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) desc)as rowNo,
    vals.val, count(*) as countt
    from abcd outer apply
         (values (a), (b), (c), (d)) vals(val)
    where val is not null
    group by vals.val
    --order by count(*) desc
) source
pivot
(
MAX(val)
for rowNo in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) piv
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain how you come up with the output?

Comment: Please make an example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: the output i just use excel to show the example..i think it needs to create a pivot so that the output will be show like that..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to unpivot the data and then aggregate:

```
select top 5 vals.val, count(*)
from t outer apply
     (values (a), (b), (c), (d)) vals(val)
group by vals.val
order by count(*) desc;
```

This puts the top 5 into separate rows rather than separate columns.

EDIT:

There are multiple ways to pivot the result.  I generally go for conditional aggregation:

```
with cte as (
      select top 5 vals.val, row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t outer apply
           (values (a), (b), (c), (d)) vals(val)
      group by vals.val
      order by count(*) desc
     )
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end) as val1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end) as val2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then val end) as val3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then val end) as val4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then val end) as val5
from cte;
```

Comment: hi gordon..thanks for the solution..i have try your solution and it works..but can you help to pivot your solution?..i try but the result returns 3 rows and have null value in it..i just want to have 1 row without null value..please help..

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Gordon's excellent answer, you need to use `ROW_NUMBER` to determine the ranking and use conditional aggregation to pivot the result:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC)
    FROM (
        SELECT
            x.val, cnt = COUNT(*)
        FROM yourTable t
        CROSS APPLY(VALUES
            (a), (b), (c), (d)
        ) x(val)
        GROUP BY x.val
    ) t
    WHERE rn <= 5
)
SELECT
    [1] = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN val END),
    [2] = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN val END),
    [3] = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN val END),
    [4] = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN val END),
    [5] = MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN val END)
FROM Cte
```

Comment: hi felix..i have try your code..but there are 2 errors..1st is at the (e) and 2nd is at the rn..for 1st error, i just remove (e)..but the 2nd error how do i fix it..please help..